# Registry HKEY USERS for powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi all I am trying to read from the registry the local user account and then pass to a variable . 
I want to do that because some software are installed there instead of HKLM. So I am using the following code.

```
$root= "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Deployment\Package\*\*"
$user=Get-ChildItem $root | where {$_.Name -like "*S-1-5*"} |select Name
Write-Host $user
```

and then

```
$soft=Get-ItemProperty"REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\$user\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"| where {$_.DisplayName -like "*$program*"} | Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion 
}    
if ($soft)
{
Write-Host "npp query = "$soft""
Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "$program already installed!" 
$array +=  $soft[0]
}
```

The only problem is that I am trying to get the S-1.... numbers that is defining the local user account but instead of that I am getting the full path .

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The part of the path you want is stored in a different property, `PSChildName`.  You can retrieve it like this:

```
$root = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Deployment\Package\"

$user = (Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse -Include "*S-1-5*").PsChildName
```

As a side note, you can resolve the SID to the user name like this:

```
$sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($user)

$userName = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```